# What is the fastest way to find an integer-valued row echelon form for a matrix with integer entries?

Tags: performance-tuning, linear-algebra

Let me begin by saying that this is my first post on StackExchange. I apologize in advance if I unwittingly break any of its unwritten rules of etiquette.

Recently, I've been trying to understand an algorithm by coding it into Mathematica. One of the main steps in the algorithm requires me to find a integer-valued row echelon form for a matrix with integer entries. There are several constraints that the input matrices satisfy. The matrices represent sparse underdetermined (never inconsistent or trivial) homogeneous linear systems. The number of columns may only take particular values fixed by the algorithm but, for the purposes of this question, it is enough to know that the number of columns is always much, much larger than the number of rows. The number of rows is also typically somewhat large and it may be the case that some number of rows are duplicates or linear combinations of other rows. Another key point is that the integer entries could generically be quite large. Therefore `Compile` was not an option for me (however if there is some magic way to do multi-precision arithmetic with `Compile` please let me know!).

My main motivation for asking this question is that this is the first time that it has actually mattered to me how efficient my Mathematica code is and I am having a very difficult time optimizing my solution attempts. First a word about data structures. I represent my sparse arrays using their rule-based form on a row-by-row basis. As a representative example, consider the following 15 X 100 matrix:

```
{{{1} -> 1, {21} -> -1, {62} -> -1, {92} -> 1}, {{2} -> 
1, {22} -> -1, {64} -> -1, {94} -> 1}, {{3} -> 
1, {23} -> -1, {65} -> -1, {95} -> 1}, {{2} -> 
1, {22} -> -1, {64} -> -1, {94} -> 1}, {{4} -> 
1, {24} -> -1, {67} -> -1, {97} -> 1}, {{5} -> 
1, {25} -> -1, {68} -> -1, {98} -> 1}, {{3} -> 
1, {23} -> -1, {65} -> -1, {95} -> 1}, {{5} -> 
1, {25} -> -1, {68} -> -1, {98} -> 1}, {{6} -> 
1, {26} -> -1, {69} -> -1, {99} -> 1}, {{55} -> -2, {56} -> 
1987, {62} -> -8, {63} -> -2, {65} -> -4, {66} -> 
1987, {72} -> -4, {73} -> -2, {82} -> -4, {95} -> 
2}, {{58} -> -2, {59} -> 
1987, {64} -> -8, {65} -> -2, {68} -> -4, {69} -> 
1987, {74} -> -4, {75} -> -2, {84} -> -4, {98} -> 
2}, {{59} -> -2, {60} -> 
1987, {65} -> -8, {66} -> -2, {69} -> -4, {70} -> 
1987, {75} -> -4, {76} -> -2, {85} -> -4, {99} -> 
2}, {{5} -> -2, {6} -> 1987, {13} -> -2, {16} -> 
1987, {22} -> -4, {23} -> -2, {32} -> 4, {45} -> -2, {55} -> 
4, {56} -> -3974, {62} -> 16, {63} -> 4, {64} -> -8, {65} -> 
4, {66} -> -3974, {72} -> 8, {73} -> 4, {82} -> 8, {94} -> 
8}, {{8} -> -2, {9} -> 1987, {15} -> -2, {19} -> 
1987, {24} -> -4, {25} -> -2, {34} -> 4, {48} -> -2, {58} -> 
4, {59} -> -3974, {64} -> 16, {65} -> 4, {67} -> -8, {68} -> 
4, {69} -> -3974, {74} -> 8, {75} -> 4, {84} -> 8, {97} -> 
8}, {{9} -> -2, {10} -> 1987, {16} -> -2, {20} -> 
1987, {25} -> -4, {26} -> -2, {35} -> 4, {49} -> -2, {59} -> 
4, {60} -> -3974, {65} -> 16, {66} -> 4, {68} -> -8, {69} -> 
4, {70} -> -3974, {75} -> 8, {76} -> 4, {85} -> 8, {98} -> 8}}
```

My main motivation for using this representation of my data is that it seems to make the implementation of an efficient pivoting strategy incredibly simple. I'm not overly wedded to this choice of data structure and would be happy to switch to something else if it allows for a better solution to the problem.

One obvious question is: Why not just use built-in functions? It seems to me that, at least naively, the out-of-the-box solution based on `RowReduce`

```
IntegerRowEchelon1[L_, n_] := (temp = 
DeleteCases[RowReduce[SparseArray[#, n] & /@ L], 0 Range[n]]; 
Drop[ArrayRules[#], -1] & /@ 
Expand[(LCM @@ Denominator[Flatten[temp]]) temp])
```

is overkill in the extreme. First of all, it seems impossible to force `RowReduce` to deliver a row echelon as opposed to a reduced row echelon form. The back-solving step of the elimination process is unnecessary for me and therefore should be avoided. Furthermore, since I am working over the integers, I have to waste time by clearing the denominators and turning the reduced row echelon form that `RowReduce` delivers into an acceptable integer-valued output. So far, however, I haven't been able to improve upon the above solution.

The essence of my question to you, the experts, is whether or not I should just go with the ridiculous work-around `IntegerRowEchelon1` or if there is a more natural lower-level solution that would work as fast or faster. There are clearly many computations done by `IntegerRowEchelon1` that could in principle be avoided but, on the other hand, `RowReduce` has undoubtedly been highly optimized by the developers at WRI. So it is not obvious to me whether or not one can do significantly better.

Finally, let me share with you two solution attempts which lose to `IntegerRowEchelon1` by factors of roughly 2 and 3 respectively. I tested them both on 1000 15 X 100 matrices with 35% of their entries filled in using `RandomInteger`. The correctness of the output was verified by applying `IntegerRowEchelon1` to both the input and the output. These solution attempts were based on a classical algorithm due to Camille Jordan. Since this algorithm was not widely known until the work of Erwin Bareiss circa 1968 (The original paper, E. H. Bareiss, "Sylvester's Identity and Multistep Integer-Preserving Gaussian Elimination", is googleable (search "Erwin Bareiss Sylvester's Identity", first link) if you want to have a look at it. I also was able to get quite a bit out of the Google Books preview for Chapter 9 of "Algorithms For Computer Algebra" by Geddes et. al. http://books.google.es/books?id=9fOUwkkRxT4C&printsec=frontcover&hl=es&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), it is usually called the Bareiss one-step fraction-free Gaussian elimination algorithm. This algorithm is exposited in many textbooks on computer algebra and is probably the simplest one that does what I want.

Although I couldn't find an answer in the documentation, I would guess that this algorithm is what Mathematica is using to forward-solve when you select the method "OneStepRowReduction." Needless to say, I tried forcing `RowReduce` to use this method but it appears to make no difference whatsoever, in either the timing or in the output. Of course, I've also considered the possibility that the reason I can't beat Mathematica is that it is using an algorithm more efficient than Bareiss's. For now, I will proceed assuming that Bareiss's algorithm is at least no worse than the algorithm(s) upon which `RowReduce` is ultimately based. For those of you with insider information, any pearls of wisdom you can share about how `RowReduce` actually works would be more than welcome.

My first attempt at coding Bareiss's algorithm looks pretty ugly but only loses to `IntegerRowEchelon1` by a factor of about 1.9:

```
IntegerRowEchelon2[L_] := (Aold = SortBy[L, #[[1, 1, 1]] &]; 
rnum = Length[Aold]; i = 1; lastpivot = 1; Anew = Aold; flag = 0; 
While[i <= rnum - 1, 
If[Aold[[i, 1, 1]] =!= Aold[[i + 1, 1, 1]], i++; lastpivot = 1; 
Continue[]]; 
For[a = i + 1, a <= rnum, a++, 
If[Aold[[i, All, 1]] =!= Aold[[a, All, 1]], 
 tempRRi = 
  Rule[#, 0] & /@ 
   Complement[Aold[[a, All, 1]], Aold[[i, All, 1]]]; 
 tempRRa = 
  Rule[#, 0] & /@ 
   Complement[Aold[[i, All, 1]], Aold[[a, All, 1]]]; 
 Aold[[a]] = Sort[Join[Aold[[a]], tempRRa]]; 
 Aold[[i]] = Sort[Join[Aold[[i]], tempRRi]]; 
 Anew[[i]] = Aold[[i]]; 
 Anew[[a]] = 
  If[Aold[[a, 1, 1]] === Aold[[i, 1, 1]], Drop[Aold[[a]], 1], 
   Aold[[a]]], 
 Anew[[a]] = 
  If[Aold[[a, 1, 1]] === Aold[[i, 1, 1]], Drop[Aold[[a]], 1], 
   Aold[[a]]]]; 
Which[Aold[[a, 1, 1]] === Aold[[i, 1, 1]], 
 Anew[[a, 1 ;; Length[Aold[[a]]] - 1, 2]] = 
  Drop[1/lastpivot (Aold[[i, 1, 2]] Aold[[a, 
         1 ;; Length[Aold[[a]]], 2]] - 
      Aold[[i, 1 ;; Length[Aold[[a]]], 2]] Aold[[a, 1, 2]]), 1], 
 True, 
 Anew[[a, 1 ;; Length[Aold[[a]]], 2]] = 
  1/lastpivot Aold[[i, 1, 2]] Aold[[a, 1 ;; Length[Aold[[a]]], 
     2]]]; If[
 Anew[[a, 1 ;; Length[Aold[[a]]] - 1, 2]] =!= 
  0 Range[Length[Aold[[a]]] - 1], 
 Anew[[{i, a}]] = DeleteCases[#, {x_} -> 0] & /@ Anew[[{i, a}]]; 
 Aold[[{i, a}]] = DeleteCases[#, {x_} -> 0] & /@ Aold[[{i, a}]], 
 flag = 1; Anew = Delete[Anew, a]; rnum--; Break[]]]; 
If[flag == 1, flag = 0; If[i != Anew[[i + 1, 1, 1, 1]], i++]; 
 Aold = Anew; Continue[]]; lastpivot = Aold[[i, 1, 2]]; i++; 
 Anew = SortBy[Anew, #[[1, 1, 1]] &]; Aold = Anew]; Anew)
```

I was sure that my second attempt was going to perform much better but it turned out to lose by a factor of about 2.8 to `IntegerRowEchelon1`

```
IntegerRowEchelon3[L_] :=
(A = SortBy[L /. Rule[{x_}, y_] :> List[x, y], #[[1, 1]] &]; 
rnum = Length[A]; i = 1; lastpivot = 1; 
While[i < rnum, 
If[A[[i, 1, 1]] != A[[i + 1, 1, 1]], i++; lastpivot = 1; 
Continue[]]; 
pivotrow = A[[i]]; (activerow = A[[#]]; 
  A[[#]] = 
   If[Length[#] == 1, {#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]]/
       lastpivot}, {#[[1, 1]], (#[[1, 2]] + #[[2, 2]])/
       lastpivot}] & /@ 
    SplitBy[Sort[
      Join[Map[{#[[1]], pivotrow[[1, 2]] #[[2]]} &, 
        If[activerow[[1, 1]] == pivotrow[[1, 1]], 
         Drop[activerow, 1], activerow]], 
       Map[{#[[1]], -If[activerow[[1, 1]] == pivotrow[[1, 1]], 
             activerow[[1, 2]], 0] #[[2]]} &, 
        Drop[pivotrow, 1]]]], #[[1]] &]) & /@ Range[i + 1, rnum]; 
A = SortBy[
 DeleteCases[DeleteCases[A, {_, 0}, {2}], {}], #[[1, 1]] &]; 
 lastpivot = pivotrow[[1, 2]]; rnum = Length[A]; i++]; 
A /. List[x_, y_] :> Rule[{x}, y])
```

At least to me,`IntegerRowEchelon3` looks much nicer than `IntegerRowEchelon2`. But it's way slower! This is quite counter-intuitive to me because, in coding `IntegerRowEchelon3`, I made a concerted effort to get rid of as much fluff as possible and be as functional as possible which I thought was "good Mathematica programming style". It was very disappointing to discover that `IntegerRowEchelon3` loses so badly to `IntegerRowEchelon1`. I must admit that I feel a bit lost at this point about issues of performance tuning and look forward to seeing alternative solutions to my problem. To be clear, at the end of the day speed is what matters and I would be more than happy to accept "high-level" solutions that beat `IntegerRowEchelon1` as well.

Comment: Hi! If you don't mind, could you please link to the book or article describing the algorithm you say you're trying to implement?

Comment: There are some unmatched brackets in your definition of `IntegerRowEchelon1`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Better now?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually what you want is `HermiteDecomposition`. It is the integer ring form of `RowReduce`; that latter, while working largely over the integers for the forward elimination, actually is an echelon form over the rational field.

As for efficiency, you'll have to experiment to see if it meets your needs. If not, feel free to post or send examples so I'll have something concrete to test.

--- edit ---

Here is some testing. I defined your input to be `m1`, and do not repeat show that definition below. First I turn it into a bona fide Mathematica `SparseArray` object.

```
m2 = Flatten[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1[[1, 1]]} -> #1[[2]] &, m1, {2}], 1];
mat = SparseArray[m2];
```

Now we get the HNF.

```
In[455]:= Timing[{uu, hh} = HermiteDecomposition[mat];]

Out[455]= {0.01, Null}
```

We have the normal form (as `uu`) and the conversion matrix (as `hh`). I'll show the former.

```
In[457]:= uu

Out[457]= {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, -1988, 
  0, -1, -994}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0, -1}, {0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0, 1987, -2, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, -1, -994, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 
  0}, {0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -1, 0, 0,
   0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

Here is a substantially larger example.

```
randomSparseIntegerMatrix[m_, n_, p_, max_] := 
 RandomChoice[{p, 1 - p} -> {1, 0}, {m, n}]*
  RandomInteger[{-max, max}, {m, n}]
```

I create a 50×250 matrix with inputs up to $10^8$ in magnitude, and sparsity of around 80%.

```
biggermat = randomSparseIntegerMatrix[50, 250, 1/5, 10^20];

In[465]:= Timing[{uubig, hhbig} = HermiteDecomposition[biggermat];]

Out[465]= {1.68, Null}
```

Hope that helps to give some idea of possibilities for using `HermiteDecomposition`.

--- end edit ---

Comment: thanks so much for the prompt response! I didn't know about `HermiteDecomposition` and will have a look at it. Actually, the example 15 X 100 matrix in my post, while in a somewhat unorthodox form, is quite representative of what I'm working with (apart from the fact that the integers in it are a bit on the smaller side) and represents a good test case. Of course you'd probably need to copy it a 100 times or so to get a timing above the machine's timing resolution but that's easy enough to do.

Comment: See edit for examples.

Comment: I tested Daniel's solution in the same way that I tested `IntegerRowEchelon2` and `IntegerRowEchelon3`. I found that it outperformed `IntegerRowEchelon1` by a factor of about 1.2. I guess this means that the extra operations performed by `IntegerRowEchelon1` are actually quite inexpensive and I shouldn't have lost any sleep over them.

Comment: However, I still think that it would be nice if there was a switch in RowReduce that would instruct the function to try and deliver a row echelon form with entries in the domain that the input matrix had entries in. The reason for this is that the Hermite normal form approach, to the best of my knowledge, will only work for principal ideal domains. On the other hand, something like Bareiss's algorithm should work in any integral domain since all one needs is a notation of exact division. To give an example, I would expect Hermite normal form to work for matrices with univariate polynomial

Comment: entries but NOT matrices with multivariate polynomial entries. Bareiss's algorithm should work fine for any polynomial ring.

Comment: Bareiss' method can be adapted to the second step (back substitution, if you are solving equations). I believe David Jeffrey has advocated for this as a canonical form. See Fraction-free matrix factors: new forms for LU and QR factors
Wenqin ZHOU (*), David J. JEFFREY. As for HNF, it requires working over a Euclidean domain.

Comment: Now that I've looked more closely I see that we are not computing the same thing. I do the HNF. What you produce appears to be either Jeffrey's "new form", or at least the forward elimination part if they also do a reverse to zero above pivots (I have to check the article on that). Offhand I do not know which is the better for your eventual purpose, not knowing the specifics thereof.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the reference. Both HNF and Bareiss's method are well-suited for my particular application. I was just making the observation that Bareiss's algorithm is more broadly applicable than HNF.